# How do I get Beats and Elite Beats?

Tags: elite-beat-agents

The normal 50, 100, 300 scores are pretty easy to figure out.  They come from how precise you timing is on a note.  Beats and Elite beats., however, are more of a mystery.  What do I have to do in order to get them?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Beat and Elite Beat indicate how well you managed a sequence of notes, from 1 to whatever, all the same color.

If every note is worth either 300 or 100 points, you get a **Beat**.
If every note is worth 300 (perfect timing), you get **Elite Beat**.

You'll see which you scored on the last note of the sequence, if you got either of them.

Also, it's worth noting that you don't gain extra points for Beats or Elite Beats. But you do gain extra health from them.